# Javascript function on submit externally?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to create a Chrome extension for a new tab page. I've written the page and have it working only I'm having a problem with moving my Javascript from inline to external.

Current index.html is looking like this:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + document.getElementById("goog").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>

<div class="container">
    <form onSubmit="return process();">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goog" placeholder="Google Search">
        <input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
    </form>
```

I've tried a few different methods of moving this into an external file but I'm not great with Javascript. I'd imagine I would need to use an event listener of some kind. I've tried placing this in search.js:

```
var form = document.getElementById("search");
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    var url="https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + document.getElementById("goog").value;
    location.href=url;
    return false;
});
```

With this amended html:

```
<form id="search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goog" placeholder="Google Search">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
</form>
```

But to no avail. Can anyone help?

Comment: there is no submit event on the input type text id=goog . add the event on the form instead.

Comment: Put the listener on the form, not the input element. The hidden submit button is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the 'submit' event to the text input element. 
You should instead attach it to the form, as it's the form what gets submitted, not only that particular input. (You already do it correctly on your current index.html document).

You can do this adding an id to the form element:

```
 <form id="your-form-id">
```

and then attaching the event to it like you're already doing:

```
var form = document.getElementById("your-form-id");
form.addEventListener("submit", function() { ...
```

Also, note that unless you've changed your html while moving the JS code to an external file, on the 'submit' event callback you're trying to get the search string from an element with id="url" while your text input element has id="goog", so you won't be able to retrieve it.

**EDIT:**

The issue seems to be that the form submit gets executed and you're redirected to the same page with a new blank input before your code can be run. 
You can avoid this calling preventDefault() on the event when receiving it so the form is not submitted and your code is run, instead of returning false at the end.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   ... your code ...
```

Comment: I've made these changes but I still can't see anything happening.

Referencing the Javascript as below:

`<script src="js/search.js"></script>`

I've amended the content of search.js too, which I've edited in the original post. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just testing this opening index.html on your browser? Do you correctly add the <script> tag with the path to your .js file?

Comment: I am just testing in the browser. Referenced in the index.html as above inside the <body> tag.

Comment: That's a good thought, I hadn't considered that it could run on page load. It's late at night now so I will try this in the morning. Appreciate your help and will keep you posted

Comment: It does not run on page load. The problem is that by default, forms will send an HTTP request to their same url if no 'action' attribute is specified, so on submit you will be redirected to the same page you are before the code in the submit callback can be executed.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. Adding the event worked perfectly. I've ended up going with an HTML solution that I'll post as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that it's possible without any Javascript. I can make a form with a method of GET and pass the contents of the form into the GET request like below:

```
<form method="GET" action="https://google.co.uk/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Google Search">
    <input type="Submit" style="display:none">
</form>
```

The above solution is correct but using this avoids any Javascript whatsoever.